# Form Edit grid addfield Value

Tags: magento-1.9

I add this column in my gird and set value 0 but show blank in edit grid

```
$fieldset->addField('category_id', 'text', array(

'label' => Mage::helper('campaign')->__('Category IDs'),
            'class' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'name' => 'category_id',
            'value' => 0, 
        ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value field is not allowed here to be used. Values are called from db field of same name. To customize the value and if you want to set some static then use renderers